# Casting Java functional interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, classcastexception, functional-interface

As always I was looking through JDK 8 sources and found very interesting code:

```
@Override
default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
    if (action instanceof IntConsumer) {
        forEachRemaining((IntConsumer) action);
    } 
}
```

The question is: how `Consumer<? super Integer>` could be an *instance of* `IntConsumer`? Because they are in different hierarchy.

I have made similar code snippet to test casting:

```
public class InterfaceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntConsumer intConsumer = i -> { };
        Consumer<Integer> a = (Consumer<Integer>) intConsumer;

        a.accept(123);
    }
}
```

But it throws `ClassCastException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: 
       com.example.InterfaceExample$$Lambda$1/764977973 
     cannot be cast to 
       java.util.function.Consumer
```

You can find this code at [java.util.Spliterator.OfInt#forEachRemaining(java.util.function.Consumer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's see the code below, then you can see why?

```
class IntegerConsumer implements Consumer<Integer>, IntConsumer {
   ...
}
```

Any class can implement multi-interfaces, one is `Consumer<Integer>` maybe implements another one is `IntConsumer`. Sometimes occurs when we want to adapt `IntConsumer` to `Consumer<Integer>` and to save its origin type (`IntConsumer`), then the code looks like as below:

```
class IntConsumerAdapter implements Consumer<Integer>, IntConsumer {

    @Override
    public void accept(Integer value) {
        accept(value.intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(int value) {
        // todo
    }
}
```

*Note*: it's the usage of [Class Adapter Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978477/difference-between-object-adapter-pattern-and-class-adapter-pattern).

**THEN** you can use `IntConsumerAdapter` both as `Consumer<Integer>` and `IntConsumer`, for example:

```
Consumer<? extends Integer> consumer1 = new IntConsumerAdapter();
IntConsumer consumer2 = new IntConsumerAdapter();
```

`Sink.OfInt` is a concrete usage of [Class Adapter Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978477/difference-between-object-adapter-pattern-and-class-adapter-pattern) in jdk-8.The downside of `Sink.OfInt#accept(Integer)` is clearly that JVM will throw a `NullPointerException` when it accepts a `null` value, so that is why `Sink` is *package* visible.

```
189  interface OfInt extends Sink<Integer>, IntConsumer {
190      @Override
191      void accept(int value);
193      @Override
194      default void accept(Integer i) {
195          if (Tripwire.ENABLED)
196              Tripwire.trip(getClass(), "{0} calling Sink.OfInt.accept(Integer)");
197          accept(i.intValue());
198      }
199  }
```

I found it why need to cast a `Consumer<Integer>` to an `IntConsumer` if pass a consumer like as `IntConsumerAdapter`?

One reason is when we use a `Consumer` to accept an `int` the compiler needs to auto-boxing it to an `Integer`. And in the method `accept(Integer)` you need to unbox an `Integer` to an `int` manually. 
In the other words, each `accept(Integer)` does 2 additional operations for boxing/unboxing. It needs to improve the performance so it does some special checking in the algorithm library.

Another reason is reusing a piece of code. The body of [OfInt#forEachRemaining(Consumer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a good example of applying  [Adapter Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978477/difference-between-object-adapter-pattern-and-class-adapter-pattern) for reusing [OfInt#forEachRenaming(IntConsumer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.IntConsumer-).

```
default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
    if (action instanceof IntConsumer) {
    //   action's implementation is an example of Class Adapter Design Pattern
    //                                   |
        forEachRemaining((IntConsumer) action);
    }
    else {
    //  method reference expression is an example of Object Adapter Design Pattern
    //                                        |
        forEachRemaining((IntConsumer) action::accept);
    }
}
```

Comment: That interface already has "forEachRemaining" that takes IntConsumer,how is it possible that "forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer> action)" will be called with object that implements IntConsumer? Unless caller specially casting it to Consumer, but why?

Comment: @tsolakp because `IntStream` is not a `Consumer<Integer>`. they are in different class hierarchies. but you can use an adapter pattern adapts a `Consumer<Integer>` to a `IntConsumer` in this case.

Answer (score 21):

Because the implementing class might implement both interfaces.

It is legal to cast any type to any interface type, **as long as the *object* being passed *might* implement the destination interface**. This is known at *compile-time* to be false when the source type is a final class that does not implement the interface, or when it can be proven to have different type parameterization that results in the same erasure. At *run-time*, if the object does not implement the interface, you'll get a `ClassCastException`. Checking with `instanceof` before attempting to cast allows you to avoid the exception.

From the Java Language Specification, [5.5.1: Reference Type Casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> 5.5.1 Reference Type Casting
>   Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type
>   T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur
>   due to the following rules.
>
> ...
>
> • If T is an interface type:
>   – If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> **Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might).**

Comment: Thank you. And what happens in case of lambda? It just infers type from the right side.

Comment: Right, with one of the key points being that an object of a functional interface type does not necessarily correspond to a lambda expression.

Comment: @AndriiAbramov, the object resulting from a lambda expression of inferred type `Consumer<? super Integer>` will not be an instance of `IntConsumer`.  The `instanceof` expression in the method you presented will evaluate to `false` in that case, with the result that the method has no observable effect.

Answer (score 10):

Note that you could have found this behavior without looking into the source code, just by looking at [the official API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-), you have linked yourself:

> #### Implementation Requirements:
>
> If the action is an instance of `IntConsumer` then it is cast to `IntConsumer` and passed to [forEachRemaining(java.util.function.IntConsumer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.IntConsumer-); otherwise the action is adapted to an instance of `IntConsumer`, by boxing the argument of `IntConsumer`, and then passed to [forEachRemaining(java.util.function.IntConsumer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.IntConsumer-).

So in either case, `forEachRemaining(IntConsumer)` will be called, which is the actual implementation method. But when possible, the creation of a boxing adapter will be omitted. The reason is that a `Spliterator.OfInt` is also a `Spliterator<Integer>`, which only offers the `forEachRemaining(Consumer<Integer>)` method. The special behavior allows treating generic `Spliterator` instances and their primitive (`Spliterator.OfPrimitive`) counterparts equally, with an automatic selection of the most efficient method.

As said by others, you can implement multiple interfaces with an ordinary class. Also, you can implement multiple interfaces with a lambda expression, if you create a helper type, e.g.

```
interface UnboxingConsumer extends IntConsumer, Consumer<Integer> {
    public default void accept(Integer t) {
        System.out.println("unboxing "+t);
        accept(t.intValue());
    }
}
public static void printAll(BaseStream<Integer,?> stream) {
    stream.spliterator().forEachRemaining((UnboxingConsumer)System.out::println);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Stream.of(1, 2, 3):");
    printAll(Stream.of(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println("IntStream.range(0, 3)");
    printAll(IntStream.range(0, 3));
}
```

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3):
unboxing 1
1
unboxing 2
2
unboxing 3
3
IntStream.range(0, 3)
0
1
2
```

Comment: good job. explain it more detailed. and it values to up-votes.

Comment: @holi-java: what a coincidence, the JRE’s `Sink.OfInt` you just added to your answer, is a real-life example of the `UnboxingConsumer`.

Comment: yes, sir. `OfInt.**(Consumer)` is a example of `UnboxingConsumer`, but I say another case. my first answer is solving his `ClassCastException` problem. after a while, my answer grow another point of view.