# Adapter Pattern Application

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, adapter

GOF has the following point for application of Adapter pattern:

> you need to use several existing subclasses, but it's impractical to adapt their
>   interface by subclassing every one. An object adapter can adapt the interface of its parent class

**What does it mean? Please give an example of the scenario? (Code is not required)**

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adapter-Any real example of Adapter Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079605/adapter-any-real-example-of-adapter-pattern)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I just want a specific example of the listed point

Comment: With respect to the specific suggestion of an *object adapter* (there's a *class adapter*, too), read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978477/difference-between-object-adapter-pattern-and-class-adapter-pattern/32795463).

Comment: a specific example of adapting multiple subclasses can be found in the linked question